# content negotiation based on language in asp.net web.api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

What is the best way to support content negotiation based on language (Accept-Language header) in the new ASP.NET web api?

The new API has a nice way of supporting content negotiation by media types (see [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters)) but I couldn't find a pointer on how we could do content negitiation based on the language header.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call the `FormatterSelector` to help it know what you want it to do. An `HttpMessageHandler`, as @AlexanderZeitler noted, is probably best for doing this at a site level. You can see a simple form of working with the `FormatterSelector` in [WebApiContrib](http://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApi.Conneg).

Hopefully this will become a new extensibility point in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MessageHandler to inspect the headers and change the accept header to match a type your custom formatter can negotiate.

Answer (score 0):

If you set set UICulture and Culture to auto in the globalization element in web.config, ASP.Net will automatically set the CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and CurrentThread.CurrentCulture based on the Accept-Language header.

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"/>
  </system.web>
```